# How to start a pod in command line without deployment in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I want to debug the pod in a simple way, therefore I want to start the pod without deployment.

But it will automatically create a deployment

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80
deployment "nginx" created
```

So I have to create the `nginx.yaml` file

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

And create the pod like below, then it creates pod only

```
kubectl create -f nginx.yaml
pod "nginx" created
```

How can I specify in the command line the `kind:Pod` to avoid `deployment`?

// I run under minikue 0.20.0 and kubernetes 1.7.0 under Windows 7

Comment: Note for new users: using so-called "naked" pods is not considered a best practice (see [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#naked-pods-vs-replicasets-deployments-and-jobs)).

Comment: The practice is not only discouraged, but the generators used in the accepted answer have been removed in 2020 from `kubectl run` (see [release notes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.18.md)).

Answer (score 56, accepted):

```
kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80 --restart=Never
```

> `--restart=Always`: The restart policy for this Pod.  Legal values [`Always`, `OnFailure`, `Never`].  If set to `Always`
>   a deployment is created, if set to `OnFailure` a job is created, if set to `Never`, a regular pod is created. For the latter two `--replicas` must be `1`.  Default `Always` [...]

see official document https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-conventions/#generators

Comment: nice explaination, hopefully it can be in official document as well. Or add something like `--kind=Pod`

Comment: @LarryCai Documented here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-conventions/#generators

Comment: This answer is now deprecated. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62036673/4470135

Comment: this will still hang deployment at the cluster.

Comment: Is there a way to specify multiple images? thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Now there are two ways one can create pod through command line.

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Never`

OR

`kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginx1 --image=nginx`

See official documentation.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators

Answer (score 5):

Use generators for this, default kubectl run will create a deployment object. If you want to override this behavior use **"run-pod/v1"** generator.

```
kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginx1 --image=nginx
```

You may refer the link below for better understanding.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/#generators

Comment: `--generator=run-pod/v1` is deprecated now and should no longer be used. Explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890718/kubectl-run-is-deprecated-looking-for-alternative

Answer (score 5):

I'm relatively new to kubernetes, but it seems it has evolved quite a bit since this question was asked. As of its latest versions(I'm running v1.16) generators are deprecated and they are completely removed in v1.18.
See the corresponding [ticket](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87077) and the [release notes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/release/notes/#deprecation-4).
Release notes explicitly say:

> Remove all the generators from kubectl run. It will now only create
>   pods.

I've tested `kubectl run` with various `--restart` flags and never got any deployments created. What we do have now is called "naked" Pod. And while you might be tempted to use it, it goes against k8s [best practices](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/overview/#naked-pods-vs-replicasets-deployments-and-jobs):

> Don’t use naked Pods (that is, Pods not bound to a ReplicaSet or
>   Deployment) if you can avoid it. Naked Pods will not be rescheduled in
>   the event of a node failure.

Answer (score -1):

When you are using "kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --port=80" it creates a deployment by default.
To create a pod you have two options.

1. kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginx --image=nginx --port=80
2. kubectl create pod nginx --image=nginx --port=80