# Why does simple kubectl(1.16) run show an error?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

**kubectl version**

```sh
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-18T14:56:51Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.13", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.2", GitCommit:"c97fe5036ef3df2967d086711e6c0c405941e14b", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-10-15T19:09:08Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

**error**
When I run `kubectl run`, an error occurs.

```
$ kubectl run nginx --image=nginx
WARNING: New generator "deployment/apps.v1" specified, but it isn't available. Falling back to "run/v1".
kubectl run --generator=deployment/apps.v1 is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 or kubectl create instead.
error: no matches for kind "Deployment" in version "apps/v1"
```

It seems like this is caused by a new version(1.16.x), doesn't it?
As far as I searched, even official documents doesn't explicitly mention something related to this situation. How can I use `kubectl run`?

Comment: It's almost always better to write a YAML file for, say, a deployment, check it into source control, and install it using `kubectl apply`; try to avoid `kubectl run` except for one-off debugging pods.  That having been said, this output sort of looks like your cluster is broken, and fixing that isn't the sort of programming question that SO focuses on.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thanks for the advice! However, k8s tutorial says readers to do so(`kubectl run`), thus it's weird the error occurs.

Comment: That's strange. What's your kubernetes version? I would say your `kubectl` is newer version then your kubernetes cluster, so on your cluster, it is still expecting to dun deployments as `deployment/v1beta1`, but `kubectl` is trying to create the deployment with the promoted `deployment/apps.v1` `apiVersion`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
kubectl create deployment --image nginx my-nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

As [kubectl Usage Conventions](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/conventions/) suggests,

> Specify the --generator flag to pin to a specific behavior when you
>   use generator-based commands such as kubectl run or kubectl expose

Use `kubectl run --generator=run-pod/v1 nginnnnnnx --image nginx` instead.

Also @soltysh  [describes well enough](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53010591/9929015) why its better to use `kubectl create` instead of `kubectl run`