# Kubectl imperative command for deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I used to create deployments quickly using imperative commands

`kubectl run nginx --image=nginx --restart=Always --port=80 --replicas=3`  .

Now run command with deployment seems to have been deprecated.  Is there any other way to do the same with `kubectl create`... with replicas and ports?

Comment: what is the problem with the run command?

Comment: it no longer creates deployments / jobs. it has been deprecated

Comment: As far as I checked in this [github pull](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/87077) ,`kubectl run` will only create Pods. All generators will be removed entirely. Worth to check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52890718/kubectl-run-is-deprecated-looking-for-alternative) stackoverflow question if you're looking for alernatives. Let me know if that's what we're you looking for.

Comment: AFAIK, the only way would be `kubectl patch`.

Comment: for me `kubectl run name --image=docker_image` will create a deployment (May 2020). However I see a deprecation message as well.

Answer (score 6):

Since the Kubernetes v1.18 the `kubectl run` will no longer create deployments but pods.

What might be used instead is the imperative option of `kubectl create deployment`. 
So the following command:

`k create deploy nginx --image nginx`

will do the trick for you. 
It will create Deployment object in imperative way. (No need for intermediate `yaml` files)

```
# Run:
kubectl create deploy nginx --image nginx && kubectl scale deploy nginx --replicas 3

# Check:
kubectl get deploy
NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
nginx                        3/3     3            3           14s
```

Note there is no `--replicas` flag of `kubectl create deployemnt` so the scaling is controlled separately.

Comment: there is a replicas flag available now (2022)!

Answer (score 3):

Try this-

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml > webapp.yaml
```

change the replicas to 5 in the yaml and create it

```
kubectl create -f webapp.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the generators were deprecated because of the pain it was to maintain that code. For easy deployment generator via CLI the best recommendation its helm3, it now doesn't need tillier and its very straightforward to use:

https://helm.sh/docs/intro/install/

Then, after installing running an Nginx deployment via CLI:

Add the repo

```
helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
```

Also, you can first check what is going to get installed by adding `--dry-run`

```
helm install Nginx bitnami/nginx --dry-run
```

Then run without `--dry-run` if you are satisfied with what is going to get deployed.

Answer (score 0):

I am using kubernetes : v1.22.5
Usage of imeperative command:

```
kubectl create deploy mydep --image=nginx --replicas=3 --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: mydep
  name: mydep
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mydep
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: mydep
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

Answer (score 0):

The imperative way to do this, including creating the replicas on the commandline without first saving the yaml and then editing the yaml, would be by running the following command:

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image nginx --replicas 3 --port 80
```

you can add the `--restart=Always` switch if you need it to the above command.

And, if you still want to save the yaml, for any reason, like pushing it to git, you should be able to redirect the above command as usual. No change in the way shell redirection works.

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image nginx --replicas 3 --port 80 --output yaml --dry-run=client > file.yaml
```

Answer (score -4):

Create nginx-deployment.yaml file with below content.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

and run `kubectl create -f nginx-deployment.yaml`

Comment: This doesnt answer the question